# How to manage "groups" in the database?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database-design

I've asked this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/774402/is-there-anything-wrong-with-having-a-table-with-one-column-mssql-server), but I don't think I got my point across.

Let's say I have the following tables (all PK are IDENTITY fields):

- People (PersonId (PK), Name, SSN, etc.)
- Loans (LoanId (PK), Amount, etc.)
- Borrowers (BorrowerId(PK), PersonId, LoanId)

Let's say Mr. Smith got 2 loans on his name, 3 joint loans with his wife, and 1 join loan with his mistress. For the purposes of application I want to GROUP people, so that I can easily single-out the loans that Mr. Smith took out jointly with his wife.

To accomplish that I added BorrowerGroup table, now I have the following (all PK are IDENTITY fields):

- People (PersonId (PK), Name, SSN, etc.)
- Loans (LoanId (PK), Amount, BorrowerGroupId, etc.)
- BorrowerGroup(GroupId (PK))
- Borrowers (BorrowerId(PK), GroupId, PersonId)

Now Mr. Smith is in 3 groups (himself, him and his wife, him and his mistress) and I can easily lookup his activity in any of those groups.

The problems with new design:

The only way to generate new BorrowerGroup is by inserting MAX(GourpId)+1 with IDENTITY_INSERT ON, this just doesn't feel right. Also, the notion of a table with 1 column is kind of weird.

I'm a firm believer in surrogate keys, and would like to stick to that design if possible.

This application does not care about individuals, the GROUP is treated as an individual

#### Is there a better way to group people for the purpose of this application?

Comment: could you provide an example of what would be in your group table please?

Comment: that's the thing, i don't need any info in that table. i don't even want that table if there's a way to group people without it. i just want to keep track of people IN GROUPS, not as individuals

Comment: Did you mean Borrowers table to have a LoanID in the second example? ie. Borrowers (BorrowerId(PK), GroupId, PersonId, LoanID)?

Comment: would i be correct in saying that you want to show each unique grouping of people per loan, but don't want to show duplicate groupings?

Comment: @codeulike: NO, Loans table has Group id ... each group can have multiple loans

Comment: Ahhhh ... I got it! Going to update ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The design of the database seems OK. Why do you have to use MAX(GourpId)+1 when you create a new group? Can't you just create the row and then use SCOPE_IDENTITY() to return the new ID?

e.g.

```
INSERT INTO BorrowerGroup() DEFAULT VALUES
SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()
```

(See [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45651/sql-how-to-get-the-id-of-values-i-just-inserted))

(edit to SQL courtesy of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/850327/how-to-insert-into-a-table-with-just-one-identity-column))

Comment: ah, I see ... I have updated the insert statement ... does that new version work?

Comment: Thanks.  I remember May 2009. Boy, that was a long time ago

Answer (score 3):

You could just remove the table `BorrowerGroups` - it carries no information. This information is allready present via the `Loans` `People` share - I just assume you have a `PeopleLoans` table.

```
People          Loans           PeopleLoans
-----------     ------------    -----------
1  Smith         6  S1    60    1   6
2  Wife          7  S2    60    1   7
3  Mistress      8  S+W1  74    1   8
                 9  S+W2  74    1   9
                10  S+W3  74    1  10
                11  S+M1  89    1  11
                                2   8
                                2   9
                                2  10
                                3  11
```

So your `BorrowerGroups` are actually almost the `Loans` - 6 and 7 with Smith only, 8 to 10 with Smith and Wife, and 11 with Smith and Mistress. **So there is no need for `BorrowerGroups` in the first place, because they are identical to `Loans` grouped by the involved `People`.**

But it might be quite hard to efficently retrieve this information, so you could think about adding a `GroupId` directly to `Loans`. Ignoring the second column of `Loans` (just for readability) the third column schould represent your groups. They are redundant, so you have to be carefull if you change them.

If you find a good way to derive a unique `GroupId` from the ids of involved people, you could make it a computed column. If a string would be okay as an group id, you could just order the ids of the people an concat them with a separator.

Group `60` with Smith only would get id `'1'`, group `74` would become `1.2`, and group `89` would become `1.3`. Not that smart, but unique and easy to compute.

Comment: This is what I was thinking, just connect the people to the loans, in a one to many relationship... each loan can have 1 to X number of people on it.

Comment: So basically a many-to-many between Loans and People--- which is what Borrowers already is. I'm beginning to think that the whole "borrower group" concept is simply redundant...

Comment: But BorrowerGroups would have more meaning that just Loans if the same group took out several loans, wouldn't it?

Answer (score 2):

use the original schema:

- People (PersonId (PK), Name, SSN, etc.)
- Loans (LoanId (PK), Amount, etc.)
- Borrowers (BorrowerId(PK), PersonId, LoanId)

just query for the data you need (your example to find husband and wife on same loans):

```
SELECT
    l.*
    FROM Borrowers            b1
        INNER JOIN Borrowers  b2 ON b1.LoanId=b2.LoanId
        INNER JOIN Loans       l ON b1.LoanId=l.LoanId
    WHERE b1.PersonId=@HusbandID
        AND b2.PersonId=@WifeID
```

Comment: this SQL will work, however, the optimum SQL is going to depend on the datasets.

Comment: @Richard, I don't understand what your are saying? If there is an index on Borrowers.PersonId then it should run very fast.

Answer (score 0):

I would do something more like this:

> - People (PersonId (PK), Name, SSN, etc.)
> - Loans (LoanId (PK), Amount, BorrowerGroupId, etc.)
> - BorrowerGroup(BorrowerGroupId (PK))
> - PersonBelongsToBorrowerGroup(BorrowerGroupId
>     (PK), PersonId(PK))

I got rid of the Borrowers table. Just store the info in the BorrowerGroup table. That's my preference.

Answer (score 0):

The consensus seems to be to omit the BorrowerGroup table and I have to agree. Suggesting that you would use MAX(groupId+1) has all sorts of ACID/transaction issues and the main reason why IDENTITY fields exist.

That said; the SQL that KM provided looks good. There are any number of ways to get the same results. Joins, sub-selects and so on. The real issue there... is knowing the dataset. Given the explanation you provided the datasets are going to be very small. That also supports removing the BorrowerGroup table.

Answer (score 0):

I would have a group table and then a groupmembers(borrowers) table to accomplish the many-to-many relationship between loans and people. This allows the tracking of data on the group other than just a list of members (I believe someone else made this suggestion?).

```
CREATE TABLE LoanGroup
(
    ID int NOT NULL 
    , Group_Name char(50) NULL 
    , Date_Started datetime NULL 
    , Primary_ContactID int NULL
    , Group_Type varchar(25)
)
```