# How to insert into a table with just one IDENTITY column?

Tags: sql, sql-server, identity

(Came up with this question in the course of trying to answer [this other one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/850017/how-to-manage-groups-in-the-database/850049#850049))

Consider the following MS-SQL table, called GroupTable:

```
GroupID
-------
1  
2  
3
```

where GroupID is the primary key and is an Identity column.

How do you insert a new row into the table (and hence generate a new ID) **without** using IDENTITY_INSERT ON?

Note that this:

```
INSERT INTO GroupTable() Values ()
```

... won't work.

edit: we're talking SQL 2005 or SQL 2008 here.

Answer (score 140, accepted):

This should work:

```
INSERT INTO GroupTable DEFAULT VALUES
```

Comment: I can't get this to work with Visual Studio 2008/SQL Express 2005.
Any ideas?

Same table layout, one column, primary key, identity(1,1).

Comment: I'm using SQL 2008 R2, no joy for me either!

Comment: Works for me on SQL Server 2008 Express.

Comment: @RomanPekar, in SqlServer 2008 and later it is possible with `merge` operator. E.g. `merge into TableName using (values (1), (2), (3)) s(n) on 1=0 when not matched then insert default values;`

Answer (score 17):

Here you go:

```
INSERT INTO GroupTable DEFAULT VALUES
```

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to insert more than one row at a time.

For e.g., to insert 30 rows.
INSERT INTO GroupTable DEFAULT VALUES
GO 30

This will insert 30 rows by incrementing the identity column each time.

Comment: Not sure about SQL 2008, but in 2008R2 this does not work (I get the generic error "Invalid syntax near 'GO'")

Comment: @Elaskanator `GO` has to be on its own line. Looks like RMK just formatted his example improperly, by forgetting to put it on a new line. `GO` is not a T-SQL keyword, rather it's a special command recognized by SSMS on how to process the preceding T-SQL

Answer (score 0):

Can you try using a Sequence or something similar?  Where you select from a Sequence and it will give you the next value in the sequence.

Comment: I think he's talking about Oracle DB

Comment: I know sequences exist in Oracle and wasn't sure what (if any) comparable thing existed in SQL Server.  That is why I suffixed it with "or something similar" and then gave a definistion of a Sequence for reference.

Comment: SQL Server 2012 has [SEQUENCE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff878091.aspx)s.

Answer (score -1):

This will work actually--

insert into TABLE default values

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).