# Adding auto-incremented values to a table with one column

Tags: sql, database, sqlite, auto-increment

I need to create a table that basically keeps a list of indices only. Therefore I've created a table with just one, auto-incremented column called 'id'. However, I can't seem to implicitly add auto-incremented values to this table.

I know that usually when you have such a column in a table (with more than just this column) you can do:

INSERT INTO TABLE (col1, col2 ...) VALUES (val1, val2 ...)

And if you don't specify the auto-incremented column, it would automatically get a value. However, things like:

INSERT INTO TABLE () VALUES ()
INSERT INTO TABLE
INSERT INTO TABLE ()

etc. all produce an error on my single-columned table. Can anyone offer a solution?
Thanks.

p.s. I'm using Sqlite, in case it matters.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to insert into a table with just one IDENTITY column (SQL Express)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1362148/how-to-insert-into-a-table-with-just-one-identity-column-sql-express)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following:

```
 INSERT INTO YOUR_TABLE(YOUR_ID) VALUES (NULL);
```

Answer (score 5):

Try this

```
INSERT INTO dbo.Table DEFAULT VALUES
```

See this answer:
[Previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1362148/how-to-insert-into-a-table-with-just-one-identity-column-sql-express)

Comment: At 3000 rep you can vote to close rather than referencing another question as your answer.

Comment: Thanks, I saw from your comment that it is better to refer to a previous answer as a comment.   I'll do that from now on.