# SQLite Insert into a table with one column that is auto incrament

Tags: sqlite, sql-insert

This should be an easy one.  I need the SQL to insert into a table that has only one column and it is and autoincrement field.

Similar to this post but SQLite (I am new to SQLite). 
[Inserting rows into a table with one IDENTITY column only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4117676/inserting-rows-into-a-table-with-one-identity-column-only)

```
    create table ConnectorIDs
    (
        ID   integer primary key AUTOINCREMENT
    );

    --none of the following work                
    INSERT INTO ConnectorIDs VALUES(DEFAULT);
    INSERT ConnectorIDs DEFAULT VALUES;
```

Yes this is strange and if you care here is the reason, if you want to tell me a better way. I have several different item tables that all can have many-to-many links between them but sparse. Instead of having n! bridge tables, or one bridge table with a "Type" that I can't guarantee truly maps to the correct table. I will have one ConnectorID table and each item with have a connectorID key. Then I can have one bridge table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Insert a `null` value:

```
INSERT INTO ConnectorIDs VALUES(NULL);
```

From the [docs](https://www.sqlite.org/autoinc.html):

> If no ROWID is specified on the insert, or if the specified ROWID has a value of NULL, then an appropriate ROWID is created automatically.